Manipulate not showing despite Plot working fine
Heyhey I am trying to solve a differential equation for the time evolution of a probability distribution. It solves just fine using NDSolveValue and I am able to plot the solution for specific times, however as soon as I try to turn this into a Manipulate Plot I end up with an empty graph. This is the code I am using:
ClearAll[P2, FPbound, test3, pde2];
WobblePeak[x_] = 
  Piecewise[{{h1, 
      x < x1}, {((h2 - h1)/2)*Cos[(Pi/(x2 - x1))*x] + ((h2 + h1)/2), 
      x1 <= x < 
       x2}, {(-(h3 - h2)/2)*Cos[(Pi/(x3 - x2))*x] + ((h3 + h2)/2), 
      x2 <= x < 
       x3}, {((h4 - h3)/2)*Cos[(Pi/(x4 - x3))*x] + ((h4 + h3)/2), 
      x3 <= x < x4}, {h4, x4 <= x}}] /. {x1 -> 10, x2 -> 12, x3 -> 13,
     x4 -> 14, h1 -> 5, h2 -> 12, h3 -> 10, h4 -> 9};
NeuB = NeumannValue[0, x == 0 || x == 15]
pde2 = D[P2[x, t], t] + 
    D[(-D[P2[x, t], x] - P2[x, t]* D[WobblePeak[x], x]), x] ==  NeuB;
molfem[measure_ : Automatic] := {"MethodOfLines", 
   "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "MeshOptions" -> MaxCellMeasure -> measure}};
FPbound = 
 NDSolveValue[{pde2, P2[x, 0] == UnitStep[x - 12]}, 
  P2[x, t], {x, 0, 15}, {t, 0, 500}, Method -> molfem[0.01]]
Manipulate[Plot[FPbound[x, t], {x, 0, 15}], {t, 0, 100}]
test3[x_] = FPbound /. t -> 100
Plot[test3[x], {x, 0, 15}, PlotRange -> Full]

I have tried replacing the variable name of t, checked the code for any weird invisible signs, tried to clear all variable names and tried finding obvious errors in the Manipulate documentation. However as of yet I still don't know why its not working. I am still rather new to the language and would appreciate any help!

Try it with FPbound = NDSolveValue[..., P2, ...] instead of NDSolveValue[..., P2[x, t], ...].

It  is  a  scoping  issue . t  outside  the  Manipulate  is  not  the  same  as  inside  of  it . Pass  the  values  explicitly, i . e ., in  the  definition  FPbound[x_, t_] = ...   and  in  Manipulate[Plot[FPbound[x, t], ... 

that worked, thanks a lot!
